# Perl JSON how to handle key overwriting while decoding a given json file

Tags: json, perl

I would like to decode a give json file which has the structure below. My problem is the following when I decode this into perl I got key conflicts with the slice. Is there a way to get a hash structure from the json decoding which doesn't overwrite the redundant elements ? I could think of arrays, any ideas and proposals are welcome.

```
 "register": {

     "name"       : "CTRL",
     "desc"       : "Control Register 1",
     "mode"       : "rw",
     "reset_value": "0x0000_0000", 
     "addr_offset": "+0x4",

     "slice": {
       "name": "Reserved",
       "msb" : 3,
       "lsb" : 2,
       "desc": "Reserved. Leave 0."
     },

     "slice": {
       "name": "en",
       "msb" : 1,
       "lsb" : 1,
       "desc": "Port enable"
     },

     "slice": {
       "name": "Lbm",
       "msb" : 0,
       "lsb" : 0,
       "desc": "Loop back mode"
     }

  },
```

Comment: It is not clear how do you decode the object into perl? Could elaborate on it?

Comment: your problem is that that is not proper JSON. keys have to be unique. you need an array of anonymous hashes instead of duplicating keys

Answer (score 5):

According to the [JSON spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-4)

> The names within an object SHOULD be unique.

So the 'correct' answer would be - don't do JSON with duplicate keys, use an array.

```
{
  "register": {
    "name":        "CTRL",
    "desc":        "Control Register 1",
    "mode":        "rw",
    "reset_value": "0x0000_0000",
    "addr_offset": "+0x4",
    "slices": [
      {
        "name": "Reserved",
        "msb":  3,
        "lsb":  2,
        "desc": "Reserved. Leave 0."
      },
      {
        "name": "en",
        "msb":  1,
        "lsb":  1,
        "desc": "Port enable"
      },
      {
        "name": "Lbm",
        "msb":  0,
        "lsb":  0,
        "desc": "Loop back mode"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This will then decode in perl:

```
my $stuff = decode_json(
   do { local $/; <$input> }
);

print Dumper $stuff;
```

And iterate with:

```
foreach my $slice ( @{$stuff -> {register} -> {slices}} ) {
   print Dumper $slice;
}
```

However if you really must, you might be able to make use of `JSON` and [incremental parsing](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emakamaka/JSON-2.53/lib/JSON.pm#INCREMENTAL_PARSING)